# Solr grouping pagination

Tags: solr, pagination, grouping

I use Solr 3.3 and i try to group result on field "result".

It works fine but i don't know how paginate results.

Parameter "numFound" contains number of result whithout grouping, so parameters "row" and "start" are not useful.

is there a solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure i understood your question, but [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters) you can see how the grouping is handled, and i guess you'll have to look and try to group.ngroups, rows and start, to have a custom paginator

if you're faceting then want to paginate, then this is not possible

Comment: @bobosh please share with us the solution. Thanks in advance.